# Update constraint does not work on UITableView snapkit

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, snapkit

When I try to update the snapkit constraint right after making the constraint I get a`Updated constraint could not find existing matching constraint to update` error. The code I am using is below:

```
let directionList = UITableView()
directionList.delegate = self
directionList.dataSource = self
directionList.tag = DIRECTIONS_TABLE_TAG
self.view.addSubview(directionList)
directionList.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
    make.width.equalToSuperview()
    make.top.equalTo(self.view.snp.bottom)
    make.left.equalToSuperview()
    make.right.equalToSuperview()
    make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-20)
}

directionList.snp.updateConstraints { (make) -> Void in
   make.top.equalTo(self.topDarkBlue.snp.bottom)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://snapkit.io/docs/) says that updateConstraints is only for updating the constants of existing constraints.

> Alternative if you are only updating the constant value of the
>   constraint you can use the method snp.updateConstraints instead of
>   snp.makeConstraints

You are not updating the constant; you are trying to assign the constraint to a new anchor.

I think what you should do is take a reference to the top constraint:

```
var topConstraint: Constraint? = nil
...
topConstraint = make.top.equalTo(self.view.snp.bottom)
```

later remove the top constraint:

```
topConstraint.uninstall()
```

Then use another block to make the new constraint.

```
directionList.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
   make.top.equalTo(self.topDarkBlue.snp.bottom)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean just the constant? I am using the updateConstraints in a `UIView.animate` so I need to keep it as updateConstraints.

Comment: the .constant property of NSLayoutConstraint.  I don't see why you can't use makeConstraints for UIView.animate; although I am unclear if calling makeConstraints calls layoutIfNeeded.  If not you call make constraints first and just put self.view.layoutIfNeeded int he animation block to trigger autolayout recalculation and the frame change.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late but might be helpful for someone, top answer has one mistake

Change line

```
topConstraint = make.top.equalTo(self.view.snp.bottom)
```

to

```
topConstraint = make.top.equalTo(self.view.snp.bottom).constraints
```

and one more thing

```
topConstraint.deactivate()
```

because uninstall has deprecated.